# Array que está se transformando em objeto

Tags: php, json, array, objetos

Ao usar a função json decode em um json, estou tendo um problema.
Quando a numeração está perfeitamente em ordem(0,1,2,3...) ele é classificado como arra:

```
[2016-08-01] => Array
    (
        [0] => 07:00:00
        [1] => 07:20:00
        [2] => 07:40:00
        [3] => 08:00:00
        [4] => 08:20:00
        [5] => 08:40:00
        [6] => 09:00:00
        [7] => 09:20:00
        [8] => 09:40:00
        [9] => 10:00:00
        [10] => 10:20:00
        [11] => 10:40:00
        [12] => 11:00:00
    )
```

Porém, quando eu preciso retirar alguns horários ele automaticamente se transforma em objeto (retirei o elemento de indice 9 e 10)

```
[2016-07-25] => stdClass Object
        (
            [0] => 07:00:00
            [1] => 07:20:00
            [2] => 07:40:00
            [3] => 08:00:00
            [4] => 08:20:00
            [5] => 08:40:00
            [6] => 09:00:00
            [7] => 09:20:00
            [8] => 09:40:00
            [11] => 10:40:00
            [12] => 11:00:00
        )
```

Gostaria de saber como evitar que isso ocorra, ou caso não dê, passar todos os meus dados para objeto, ou todos os dados para array.

Comment: Como você está fazendo essa retirada?

Comment: vc passa o segundo argumento como `true` sempre?

Comment: Exato deve colocar o segundo argumento do `json_decode` como `true` se quiser que tranforme em array em vez de obj

Comment: Eu tenho uma função que verifica os horarios disponiveis de um profissional. Faço uma serie de verificacoes para se te excecoes, horarios preenchidos, bloqueios. Então, ao chegar no final da função, o meu array inicial ja sofreu muita alteração. Basicamente eu tirei um item daquele array com o unset();

Comment: Perfeito. O parametro true funcionou. Obrigado.

Comment: Então vc está fazendo um cast aí nessas validações.

Comment: Acrescente o formato do JSON e como está fazendo a captação e retirada dos dados na pergunta, senão não dá pra responder objetivamente. É um problema bem simples, mas precisa destes dados pra que fiquem coerentes as respostas com a pergunta.

Answer (score 2):

Amigo antes de usaro objeto forçe um cast para array com

```
$meu_array = (array)$obj;
```

Assim ele sempre será array.